# I can not set Padding or Margins in CSS

Tags: css, padding, margins

I am making a portfolio web site I got a error,

That I cant set a padding-top or a margine top to my text
here its look like:

[Screen look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS6R1.png)

[developer tool look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkF8q.png)

but i want to get it like this:
[What I wanna get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOTDS.png)

```css
#skill {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 65rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.skillTitle {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  /* Add padding-top here */
}

.skillDescription {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 50rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="skill">
  <span class="skillTitle">What I do</span> <br />
  <span class="skillDescription">I am a passionate web developer and UI/UX designer, dedicated to creating intuitive,
    user-friendly interfaces and seamless web experiences. My expertise lies in crafting visually
    appealing websites with a focus on functionality and accessibility.</span
  >
  <div class="skillBars"></div>
</section>
```

I wanna know why this happening and how I fix his this error!

Comment: Make your ```span``` to a block level element to adjust it's *margin* and *padding*.

Comment: `span` is not a good element for containing text on its own, as it's an "inline" element, mainly for wrapping around bits of content within a larger block. You'd be better off using paragraph `<p>` elements, which are "block-level" elements. Margin and padding mainly work on block-level elements and not on inline elements. You can change that by setting inline elements like `span` to `display: block` or even `display: inline-block`, but for general content like you have there's no point to using a span in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just overriding your style.
Check on [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) of padding to see how it works. Basically when doing `padding: 0 2rem;` you are reseting the top padding. For `margin-top` you are just setting twice and the last one is the only one that gets painted.

```
.skillDescription {
    padding-top: 1rem; <- this gets override by last line ------
    margin-top: 1rem; <- this gets override by next line       |
    margin-top: 3rem;                                          |
    color: darkgrey;                                           |
    font-weight: 100;                                          |
    font-size: 1rem;                                           |
    font-style: italic;                                        |
    max-width: 50rem;                                          |
    padding: 0 2rem;  < ---------------------------------------
}
```

To solve it, you can just do:

```
.skillDescription {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-style: italic;
    max-width: 50rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

You can change the `padding` first value if you want more padding in top-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

add display: inline-block to .skillTitle because span has displayed inline

Answer (score -3):

You should use div instead of span for skillDescription and then margin-top will work. Span is mostly used to color part of a text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).